# laravel vuex not reterned data from database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, vue.js

I'm in new coding I clone this https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa laravel template to create a new project I'm created another table to store articles and this is my controller. this not returns any data from database please help me.

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Article::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with `vuex`, you mean this method isn't returning any results from your (assumed) MySQL database?

Comment: this laravel template is created with Vue + VueRouter + Vuex + VueI18n . I'm setup route in correctly data not showing

Comment: It seems you're not understanding the separation between client and server. What you posted is from a Laravel controller, which runs server side, so would be querying a database on your server. Vuex, on the other hand, is client side, meaning it is browser based. Vuex does not query data through Laravel. You need to send a request from your client to fetch the data and then store the response data in vuex.

Comment: i understand laravel and vuex my problem is querying from database with controller. see above ArticleController my route is Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController'); and i'm trying this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/article but not return any data. if this problem from vuex or my code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `vuex`. If your route to `/article` is not returning data, then either you're request is failing or there are no matching results for your query. The only way for `Article::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()` to not return anything is if your `articles` table is empty.

Comment: i'm also added some data to an article table

Comment: data store to this table no problem with this controller ` public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $currentuserid = Auth::user()->id;
        Article::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'user_id' => $currentuserid
        ]);
    }` .   only problem with get data from database

Comment: Have you verified your request is even reaching the `index` method? Does the web inspector show any errors in either the request or response? Do the Laravel logs show anything? Like I said above, if your request is going through and you have data that query would return everything without a problem.

Comment: no errors from index method.

Comment: this is my returned page https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1uwdoyd77zno9a/Screenshot%20%281%29.png?dl=0

Comment: K, that's a 404 error. 404 means not found, as in the page you are looking for is not found. Your route is not going to `/article`. Might want to take a look at the URL your request is going to and then check your route definitions.

Comment: my route Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController'); this route works store data but not working in get data from database

Comment: see this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu4cx75psuvzhk1/Screenshot%20%282%29.png?dl=0. works in get user data. if this problem in vuejs or vuex or vuejs router

Comment: Literally nothing to do with any of those. You've defined your route incorrectly. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your route definition:

```
Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController');
```

That needs to be:

```
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');
```

No leading slash.

When you use `Route::resource` you are in fact defining routes for `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE`. It's directly related to your model `Article`.

**Update**

Change web.php to this:

```
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');

// this is always the last route in the file
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```

Comment: i'm removed slash but not working. my controller https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ra2ecp6dvt7pbu/ArticleController.php?dl=0. my route https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmgbfm9i2t3fgxi/web.php?dl=0. my article model https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ebbfi4o8kb1uy6/Article.php?dl=0.

Comment: Move `Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');` above the catch all get route in your `routes.php` file

Comment: `web.php`, my bad. The second image you linked.

Comment: Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController'); this route also in web.php

Comment: sorry for my poor English I'm writing this all text with Grammarly so thank you again.